# Alternate to apt task in java 1.8

Tags: java, ant

I am migrating from java 1.7 to Java 1.8. I have an apt task inside `build.xml`. I see that Java 1.8 doesn't have this tool.

I tried the below options:

1. Copied the ant executable from 1.7 to 1.8 getting
   `Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.apt.Main`
2. What is the alternative to apt task? Found javac does annotation processing but cannot correlate to the already existing attributes.

Here is my apt task:

```
`<apt srcdir="@{srcdir}" 
 destdir="@{destdir}"
 gendir="@{tempdir}"
 classpathref="_pageflow.build.classpath"
 sourcepathref="@{sourcepathref}"
 srcExtensions="*.jpf,*.jpfs,*.app,*.jsfb,*.java" 
 processorOptions="web.content.root=@{webcontentdir}"
 debug="true"
 nocompile="@{nocompile}"/>`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run ant apt task on java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733125/how-to-run-ant-apt-task-on-java-1-8)

Comment: The same question was asked. I didn't find any solution there.

Comment: Use the `javac` task.

Comment: @CAustin  I have used javac task and I was able to bypass this error.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKrishnaKomaravolu: Could you share your ```javac``` syntax in this case?